# correct of use of quoteSmart DB_Common Pear

Tags: php, pear, data-objects

I am trying to use quoteSmart to safely format my input, however it always comes back as empty when I am using quoteSmart leading me to assume that I am doing something wrong or not calling it in the right way ?

```
$user= new DataObjects_user;
$password=mysql_escape_string(($password));

DB_DataObject::debugLevel(5);

$username=$_REQUEST['username'];
$password=encryptpass($_REQUEST['password']);

$user->query("select activated,userid,email,username from {$user->__table} where (username = ".$user->quoteSmart($username)." or email=".$user->quoteSmart($username).") AND password =".$user->quoteSmart($password)." ");

if($user->fetch())
{ //more code here
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try to understand [how to use DB_DataObjects correctly](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db-dataobject.intro-purpose.php). You are not supposed to write your own SQL with them.

If you only want to send your own SQL, use PDO instead.